# Fechando modalpopupextender no click do botão

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou usando um modalpopupextender com C# .NET. Quando eu clico em botão da minha gridview, ele chama o popup para editar as informações necessárias. Quando vou clicar no atualizar ou no cancelar, não acontece nada! É como se ele não enxergasse o codebehind!

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Se eu entendi sua duvida, para fechar "Cancelar" utilize a propriedade **CancelControlID** do ModelPopup, informe o ID do botão cancelar, é a forma mais fácil sem que se tenha que fazer programação para isto.
Para o Atualizar, utilize a propriedade **"OkControlID"**, dessa forma você programa o botão "Atualizar" para que as informações vão para o banco, enquanto a propriedade **"OkControlID"** do ModelPopup fecha o Model.
Para mostrar ao usuário que a atualização foi feito, você pode deixar uma Label direto na página ao invés de deixar no Model para que o usuário visualize.

Comment: Então, eu estou usando essas propriedades, o que acontece é que eles não estão funcionando! Ele nem atualiza a minha gridview nem cancela o modalpopup!

Comment: Se você colocar um breackpont no método do botão atualizar , ele reconhece que o método foi chamado? Dependendo da forma que foi programado,  verifique se não esqueceu de colocar o databind() para atualizar o grid.

Answer (score -2):

Se o caso é fechar o Modal, esconda o seu modal no evento click do botão:

```c#
SeuModal.Hide();
```

Comment: Já tentei isso velho! Mas não está funcionando também!